# MongoDB: Conditional select from one collection based on another collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm fairly new to MongoDB and need help doing a select, or perhaps some sort of left join, on one collection based on another collection's data.

I have two collections, animals and meals, and I want to get the animal(s) that has had it's last registered meal after a certain date (let's say 20171001) to determine if the animal is still active.

```
collection animals:
{
    name: mr floof,
    id: 12345,
    lastMeal: abcdef
},
{
    name: pluto,
    id: 6789,
    lastMeal: ghijkl
}

collection meals:
{
    id: abcdef,
    created: 20171008,
    name: carrots
},
{
    id: ghijkl,
    created: 20170918,
    name: lettuce
}
```

So the expected output of the query in this case would be:

```
{
    name: mr floof,
    id: 12345,
    lastMeal: abcdef
}
```

As Mr Floof has had his last meal 20171008, i.e. after 20171001.

Hope I was clear enough, but if not, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Try `db.animals.aggregate([ { "$lookup": { "from": "meals", "localField": "lastMeal", "foreignField": "id", "as": "last_meal" } }, { "$unwind": "$last_meal" }, { "$match": { "last_meal.created": { "$gt": 20171001 } } } ])`. More info [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21612). You can use $project after $match stage to format the response to exclude joined fields. Something like `{ $project: {"last_meal":0} }`

Comment: Thank you! Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query.

```
db.animals.aggregate([ [
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "meals",
      "localField": "lastMeal",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "last_meal"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$last_meal"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "last_meal.created": {
        "$gt": 20171001
      }
    }
  }
])
```

More info [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21612).

You can use `$project` with exclusion after `$match` stage to format the response to exclude joined fields. Something like `{ $project: {"last_meal":0} }`

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB supports  joins with `$lookup` ,  In your case you can use query like:-

```
    db.animals.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "meals",
          localField: "lastMeal",
          foreignField: "id",
          as: "last_meal"
        }
   },
  {
   $match: { 
          "created" : {
                $gt: "date" //your date format
          }
       } 
 }
])
```

thanks !

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried this out yet, but how does this select conditionally by the date (`created` key)? Wouldn't I get all meals in this case?

Comment: sorry misunderstood the question, please try now i have modified the query.

Comment: Thanks. Stupid question perhaps, but will the match be on the aggregated result for animals or extracted directly on the meals collection?

Comment: ofcourse ,it will be on aggregation result. it works on pipeline concept. if you want you can change the sequence to "match" first then aggregate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm however going to go with Veeram's reply as the `$unwind`feature was pretty neat.