# Mongoose query document by field value and subdocument field value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and trying to get document by specific value of field on it and subdocument field's specific value. I dig a lot but I was unable to find anything matching - I am also new to MongoDb.

So my schema looks like :

```
messageSchema = Schema candidateId: {type: string},

template: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'MessageTemplate'},

messageTemplate = Schema name:{type: string}, isActive:{type: boolean}
```

So I want to get all messages that have certain `candidateId` and `messageTemplate.isActive` equal to `true`.

I couldn't figure out query so I am doing work around like this

```
Message.find({candidateId: candidateId})
.populate('template')
.then(res => res.fileter(message => message.template.isActive)
```

It's working but I'm guessing it's possible to create better query, any help will be great.

Comment: You can try `Message.aggregate([  {
    "$match": {
      "candidateId": candidateId
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "name of message template collection",
      "localField": "template",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "messagetemplate"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$messagetemplate"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "messagetemplate.isActive": true
    }
  }
])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Conditional select from one collection based on another collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752429/mongodb-conditional-select-from-one-collection-based-on-another-collection)