# Check if data exists in an other collection before retrieving documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hello here is my problem: is it possible to get all the data from the "job" collection but only if the key I send in the url is one of the keys from the "person" collection?

My schema:

```
var job = Schema ({
    name: String,
    date: Date
});

var person = Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    key: String
});
```

I'm working with NodeJS so my code would look like this:

```
router.route('/jobs/:key')
    .get(function(req, res, next) {
            Models.Job
            //if req.params.key is in the "person" collection
                .find({})
                .exec(function(err,jobs) {
                if (err){
                    throw err;
                }else{
                    res.json({jobs});
                }
            });
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Is job collection linked to person collection ? If yes you can use `$lookup` to join collection followed by match to check for key. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752429/mongodb-conditional-select-from-one-collection-based-on-another-collection/47754107#47754107) may help

Comment: Seems like an odd query to me, so there is no link between `Job` and `Person`? You just want to display all jobs if `key` matches a `Person` record?

Comment: @James yes that's what I want